# Computing reconciled prediction intervals when forecasting logged outcome variable using fable

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

EDIT: Is seems like the dev version of fabletools (.3.2.9000) includes the capability to do what I want via the boostrap option. I'm leaving this question unanswered until things get formally released.

I have a series of grouped forecasts that I'd like to reconcile (ideally via MinT, as below) in a way the preserves the ability to generate prediction intervals. [This link](https://otexts.com/fpp3/rec-prob.html) seems to imply such a thing is possible (both theoretically and via the fable package) via the bootstrap option, but the default interface does not seem to work-- which is to say the forecasted values are point estimates only. [The example this post partially borrows from](https://otexts.com/fpp3/prison.html) has prediction intervals, albeit no `log` transform and no bootstrapping.

Is there a way to generate forecasted prediction intervals for a reconciled set of log-transformed outcome variable using fable? Is such a thing even theoretically possible/sensible?

```r
library('fable', quietly = TRUE)
library('tsibble', quietly = TRUE)
library('lubridate', quietly = TRUE)
library('dplyr', quietly = TRUE)

prison <- readr::read_csv("https://OTexts.com/fpp3/extrafiles/prison_population.csv") %>%
  mutate(Quarter = yearquarter(Date)) %>%
  select(-Date)  %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(Gender, Legal, State, Indigenous),
             index = Quarter) %>%
  relocate(Quarter)
#> Rows: 3072 Columns: 6
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (4): State, Gender, Legal, Indigenous
#> dbl  (1): Count
#> date (1): Date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

prison_gts <- prison %>%
  aggregate_key(Gender * Legal * State, Count = sum(Count)/1e3)


fit <- prison_gts %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) <= 2014) %>%
  model(base = ARIMA(log(Count))) %>%
  reconcile(
    bottom_up = bottom_up(base),
    MinT = min_trace(base, method = "mint_shrink")
  )
fc <- fit %>% select(Gender, Legal, State, MinT) %>% forecast(h = 8, bootstrap = TRUE, times = 10)

fc %>%
  filter(is_aggregated(State), is_aggregated(Gender),
         is_aggregated(Legal), .model == 'MinT') %>%
  autoplot(prison_gts, alpha = 0.7, level = 90)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest development version of fabletools allows you to probabilistically reconcile any forecast if you use sample/bootstrapped forecasts. Try updating the `{fabletools}` and `{distributional}` packages to use these new features. More discussion/information about these changes can be found here: https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/365

```r
library('fable', quietly = TRUE)
library('tsibble', quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tsibble'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, union
library('lubridate', quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tsibble':
#> 
#>     interval
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library('dplyr', quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

prison <- readr::read_csv("https://OTexts.com/fpp3/extrafiles/prison_population.csv") %>%
  mutate(Quarter = yearquarter(Date)) %>%
  select(-Date)  %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(Gender, Legal, State, Indigenous),
             index = Quarter) %>%
  relocate(Quarter)
#> Rows: 3072 Columns: 6
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (4): State, Gender, Legal, Indigenous
#> dbl  (1): Count
#> date (1): Date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

prison_gts <- prison %>%
  aggregate_key(Gender * Legal * State, Count = sum(Count)/1e3)


fit <- prison_gts %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) <= 2014) %>%
  model(base = ARIMA(log(Count))) %>%
  reconcile(
    bottom_up = bottom_up(base),
    MinT = min_trace(base, method = "mint_shrink")
  )
fc <- fit %>% select(Gender, Legal, State, MinT) %>% forecast(h = 8, bootstrap = TRUE, times = 10)

fc %>%
  filter(is_aggregated(State), is_aggregated(Gender),
         is_aggregated(Legal), .model == 'MinT') %>%
  autoplot(prison_gts, alpha = 0.7, level = 90)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>